# Triggering GitLab job when certain files/directories were changed compared to the previous commit

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

As far as I understand a job with the following code is executed when there are changes between two branches:

```
    - changes: 
      - deployment/images/**/*
```

Is there a way to trigger jobs based on the difference between the current and the previous commits. I want to have the following scenario:

- pushed 1 commit -> changes in deployment/images -> trigger large pipeline
- pushed 2 commit -> changes elsewhere -> trigger small pipeline (since the functionality in deployment/images was tested by previously triggered job)
- pushed 3 commit -> changes in deployment/images relative to 2 commit -> trigger large pipeline again
  etc

Comment: I believe the `changes:` rule you describe would accomplish this when placed on the job(s) that make the pipeline 'large' -- if I'm understanding you correctly. The behavior may differ between branch and MR pipelines. You can also explicitly [specify the ref being compared](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangescompare_to). For branch pipelines, it just checks against the changes in the commit by default and for MR pipelines, it checks the diff between the commit and HEAD of the target branch.